# split matched array and unmatched array using Javascript / Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I fetched data from database so its coming in string format and I want to check this string with my array data

- my string values come like

```js
const input = "fish.jpg\nanimal.jpg\nfish.pdf\nanimal.pdf\nmammal_bio.pdf\nfish_bio.jpg\nfruit_bio.pdf"
```

I want to compare this data with my array which contain

```js
check=["mammal_bio.pdf","animal_bio.pdf","fruit_bio.pdf","tree_bio.pdf"]
```

So i want to compare all the array values which contain `_bio.pdf` and store them as

- `matchedArray=["mammal_bio.pdf","fruit_bio.pdf"]`
- `unmatchedArray=["animal_bio.pdf","tree_bio.pdf"]`

Comment: What is type of input variable? just string or array of strings?

Comment: Its comes in string format @jiholee

Comment: so, input just can be a filename like ```fish.jpg```?

Comment: or if it contains multiple filename, what is separator?

Comment: It separate with `\n` as every output comes differently @jiholee

Comment: Hello @jiholee its like you fetch name from database so you get all name present inside database so you store this in one variable and whenever you call you get this names

Comment: Ok, i understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get matched and unmatched using `Array.filter` and `String.split`:

```js
const input = "fish.jpg\nanimal.jpg\nfish.pdf\nanimal.pdf\nmammal_bio.pdf\nfish_bio.jpg\nfruit_bio.pdf";
const check = ["mammal_bio.pdf","animal_bio.pdf","fruit_bio.pdf","tree_bio.pdf"];

const inputArray = input.split("\n");
const matchedArray = check.filter(e => inputArray.includes(e));
const unmatchedArray = check.filter(e => !matchedArray.includes(e));

console.log(inputArray);
console.log(matchedArray);
console.log(unmatchedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const input ="fish.jpg\nanimal.jpg\nfish.pdf\nanimal.pdf\nmammal_bio.pdf\nfish_bio.jpg\nfruit_bio.pdf"
const checkArray=["mammal_bio.pdf","animal_bio.pdf","fruit_bio.pdf","tree_bio.pdf"]
const matchedArray=checkArray.filter((e)=>input.split('\n').indexOf(e)!== -1);
const unmatchedArray=checkArray.filter((e)=>input.split('\n').indexOf(e)=== -1)
console.log(matchedArray, unmatchedArray);
```

Please note that input has a separator \n between filename

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a single loop over the `check` array.

```js
const input =
  "fish.jpg\nanimal.jpg\nfish.pdf\nanimal.pdf\nmammal_bio.pdf\nfish_bio.jpg\nfruit_bio.pdf";

const check = [
  "mammal_bio.pdf",
  "animal_bio.pdf",
  "fruit_bio.pdf",
  "tree_bio.pdf",
];

const inputArr = input.split("\n");

const result = check.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (inputArr.includes(curr)) acc[0].push(curr);
    else acc[1].push(curr);
    return acc;
  },[[], []]);

const [matchedArray, unmatchedArray] = result;
console.log(matchedArray);
console.log(unmatchedArray);
```